# How to implement DELETE method in axios and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I cannot implement delete button.
I have api endpoint 'DELETE /.../{id}'. 
Have ApiService.js:

```
deleteById(id) {
        return axios.delete(`${ACCOUNT_API_BASE_URL}/${id}`)
    }
```

and here is my class:

```
class Account extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            item: {
                id: props.match.params.id,
                name: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                link: ''
            }
        };
        this.deleteById = this.deleteById.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        // eslint-disable-next-line
        if (this.state.item.id === -1) {
            return -1
        }

        ApiService.fetchAccountById(this.state.item.id)
            .then(response => this.setState({
                item: {
                    name: response.data.name,
                    email: response.data.email,
                    password: response.data.password,
                    link: response.data.link
                }
            }))
    }


    deleteById(id) {
        ApiService.deleteById(id)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{this.state.item.name}</h3>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.item.id}
                    <li className={c.itemEmail}>Email: {this.state.item.email}</li>
                    <li>Password: {this.state.item.password}</li>
                    <li>Link: {this.state.item.link}</li>
                </ul>
                <button onClick={this.deleteById(this.state.item.id)}>Delete</button>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

It deletes data after requesting page(get method), but not by clicking delete button.

If I set `this.deleteById` to `<button onClick=` to , I receive: 
'DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/.../undefined 400'

Answer (score 2):

First, you are removing the `id` property from you item in componentDidMount:

```
ApiService.fetchAccountById(this.state.item.id)
            .then(response => this.setState({
                item: { // now item doesn't have id anymore
                    name: response.data.name,
                    email: response.data.email,
                    password: response.data.password,
                    link: response.data.link
                }
            }))
```

So keep your `id` like this:

```
ApiService.fetchAccountById(this.state.item.id)
                .then(response => this.setState({
                    item: {
                        id: this.state.item.id,
                        name: response.data.name,
                        email: response.data.email,
                        password: response.data.password,
                        link: response.data.link
                    }
                }))
```

Second, you are executing the function instead of passing the function to onClick, change your onClick value to:

```
onClick={() => {this.deleteById(this.state.item.id)}}
```

Comment: no it doesnt work, says /api/.../undefined instead of /api/.../23

Comment: You are also removing the `id` from item in componentDidMount, that's why `this.state.item.id` is undefined, I modified the answer, check it out.

Comment: How could I update state(if its about state), because after delete button I redirecting to other URL, and there i still see old data and only after refresh page it changes?

Comment: @andrew17 is your `<button>` inside a `<form>` tag? If so, the button may be acting like a submit button and triggering the form. You probably want to set the type of the `<button>` to `type="button"` so that it doesn't act like a submit.

Comment: One thing on the id being in the state _and_ the props: if the id sent to the props ever changed, because most of the time you are relying on the ID in state, then you might end up with a bug here. It's probably best to always use the ID from props, and not store it in the state, unless you expect that id to change, but then you probably need to change the ID at the higher level as well. Also, the key probably should be the ID. If this is the case, then if the id changes, a new instance of the component will be made (which accidentally fixes the bug).

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => this.deleteById(this.state.item.id)}>Delete</button>
```